# Attaching stringers to 2x6 rim joist using simpson LSC connector

Tags: deck

I'm in the process of building a deck (more like a small landing with some stairs), and this is my first DIY building project. I've framed the landing, and am now planning the stringers and railing.

Here is a photo of the deck so far:
[image]

The rim joist (which also acts as the beam) comprises a pair of 2x6's, and my intention is to use this as the header to which the stringers will be attached.

In order to attach the stringers, I'd like to use the simpson LSC adjustable stringer connectors as they look quite easy to install.

Now in the [Simpson Wood Construction Connector reference manual](https://www.strongtie.com/resources/literature/wood-construction-connectors-catalog),  it says the following:

> May be installed flush with the top of the carrying member (typically
> suitable for 2x10 or 2x12 header / rim board) or lower on the face
> (typically suitable for a 2x12 header / rim board).

and shows the following image:

[image]

The image shows that a minimum of 4.125 inches of the vertical portion of the connector must be in contact with the header. The 2x6 header has a width of 5.5 inches, which would give me 1.375 inches to spare.

I often find people installing "dropped headers" (to extend the width of the header), and I'm not quite sure why - perhaps it is to accommodate higher risers, but in my case, so long as I can fit at least 4.125 inches of the riser on the header, and not exceed 2.625 inches below the bottom edge of the header, will I be fine?

I'd appreciate any guidance here.

Comment: If you want your top step flush with the deck, then the hanger will work fine. If you want to step down off your deck onto the first tread, then you need a dropped header or a different stringer strategy. Does that clarify?

Comment: Ah, right, the riser heights should not vary too much, and if I didn't have it flush with the deck, then the last riser would be way too short. That's the part that hadn't clicked in my head. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. For anyone else reading this, code usually stipulates that riser heights are within 3/8" of each other across the entire run of steps.

Comment: Have you gotten your stringer material already? Are they precut, or will you cut them yourself?

Comment: A dropped header makes the railing easier. The post on the edge of the deck is directly in line with the post at the bottom of the stairs. If the first tread is level with the deck, a small section of railing and another post will be required before the railing starts its downward slope.

Comment: If you opt for full width, you’ll almost certainly need a center stringer. And prepare to do some aggressive landscaping (ie, removing or adding dirt) to make a precut stringer work for you. (Hint: I despise precut stringers. Cut stringers take all of 7 steps to calculate.)

Comment: I'll be cutting the stringers myself, and am looking forward to the planning exercise (which I'll validate with an online tool once I've done my own math). I imagine I'll need at least four. My plan for railing is to use blocking on the inside edges of the outermost stringers to support the two 4x4 posts at bottom of the stairs.  For the four railing posts on landing, am planning on again using blocking. These four posts will be offset from the end joists (and not flush with any joists or beam or ledger).  The width of the stairs will be narrower than the width of the landing.

Comment: Strongly recommend this article for stringer layout: https://www.jlconline.com/how-to/framing/an-evolution-in-laying-out-stair-stringers_o